# Java trying to extract data according to timestamps in sql, returning inaccurate results

Tags: java, mysql, date, calendar, timestamp

I am trying to extract data from mysql tables according to timestamps like 'Top votes of the Month' and 'Top votes of the week'
This is mysql statement for collecting top vote of the week (week 4)

```
"SELECT * FROM studentid.questions WHERE vote IN (SELECT MAX(vote) FROM studentid.questions WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '"+currentYear+"-"+currentMth+"-19 00:00:00' AND '"+currentYear+"-"+currentMth+"-24 23:59:59');
```

This is mysql statement for collecting top vote of the month (may)

```
"SELECT * FROM studentid.questions WHERE vote IN (SELECT MAX(vote) FROM studentid.questions WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '"+currentYear+"-05-01 00:00:00' AND '"+currentYear+"-05-31 23:59:59')"
```

Somehow, the sql statement returns results OUTSIDE of the date ranges, for example, if in the month of may, there is a data with votes equal to another data in the month of february, it will display both of them, when it should only display from may...
[sql results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Iwr.png)

Comment: Use parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: @The Impaler by parameters do u mean using sql functions like Year(), Month() etc.?

Comment: no I guess he means to place question marks in the statement and next replace them with a list of parameters as explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem you describe is probably due to the time zone difference between the server and your app, or from the way you are using parameters. If it's the latter you should change the code to use JDBC parameters as shown below:

First you compute the "from" and "to" timestamps in Java, and then you apply them:

```
Timestamp fromTS = ...
Timestamp toTS = ...

PreparedStatement ps = conn.createStatement(
  "SELECT * " +
  "FROM studentid.questions " +
  "WHERE vote IN ( " +
  "  SELECT MAX(vote) FROM studentid.questions " +
  "  WHERE timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?)"
);
ps.setTimestamp(1, fromTS);
ps.setTimestamp(2, toTS);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
...
```